# Correct Implementation of Vector 3 in c++

Tags: c++

I have just begun dabbling in c++.  Is this the correct implementation of a vector 3?  I don't want to leak any memory, or do anything that is just bad form in c++.  Are my operator overload signatures correct?

```
class Vector
{
private:
    double _x;
    double _y;
    double _z;
    double LengthSquared();
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector& vector);
public:
    Vector();
    Vector(double x, double y, double z);
    ~Vector();
    Vector(Vector& other);  
    double GetX() const;
    double GetY() const;
    double GetZ() const;
    double Length();    
    Vector& Normalize();
    double DotProduct(const Vector& vector) const;
    Vector CrossProduct(const Vector& vector);
    bool operator==(const Vector& vector) const;
    bool operator!=(const Vector& other) const;
    Vector& operator+=(const Vector& vector);
    Vector operator+(const Vector& vector) const;
    Vector& operator-=(const Vector& vector);
    Vector operator-(const Vector& vector) const;
    Vector& operator*=(double val);
    double operator*(const Vector& vector) const;
    Vector operator*(double val) const; 
};

Vector::Vector() : _x(0.0), _y(0.0), _z(0.0)
{
}

Vector::Vector(double x, double y, double z) : _x(x), _y(y), _z(z)
{
}

Vector::~Vector()
{
}

Vector::Vector(Vector& other) : _x(other._x), _y(other._y), _z(other._z)
{
}

double Vector::GetX() const
{
    return _x;
}

double Vector::GetY() const
{
    return _y;
}

double Vector::GetZ() const
{
    return _z;
}

double Vector::Length()
{
    return sqrt(LengthSquared());
}

double Vector::LengthSquared()
{
    return (_x * _x + _y * _y + _z * _z);
}

Vector& Vector::Normalize()
{
    double length = Length();

    if(length >0)
    {
        _x = _x / length;
        _y = _y / length;
        _z = _z / length;
    }
    else
    {
        _x = 0;
        _y = 0;
        _z = 0;
    }

    return *this;
}

double Vector::DotProduct(const Vector& vector) const
{
    return _x * vector.GetX() + _y * vector.GetY() + _z * vector.GetZ();        
}

Vector Vector::CrossProduct(const Vector& vector)
{
    double nx = _y * vector.GetZ() - _z * vector.GetY();
    double ny = _z * vector.GetX() - _x * vector.GetZ();
    double nz = _x * vector.GetY() - _y * vector.GetX();

    return Vector(nx, ny, nz);
}

bool Vector::operator==(const Vector& vector) const
{
    if(this == &vector)
        return true;

    if((_x == vector.GetX()) && (_y == vector.GetY()) && (_z == vector.GetZ()))
        return true;

    return false;
}

bool Vector::operator!=(const Vector& vector) const
{
    return !(*this == vector);  
}

Vector& Vector::operator+=(const Vector& vector)
{   
    _x += vector.GetX();
    _y += vector.GetY();
    _z += vector.GetZ();

    return *this;
}

Vector Vector::operator+(const Vector& vector) const
{
    return Vector(_x, _y, _z) += vector;
}

Vector& Vector::operator-=(const Vector& vector)
{   
    _x -= vector.GetX();
    _y -= vector.GetY();
    _z -= vector.GetZ();    

    return *this;
}

Vector Vector::operator-(const Vector& vector) const
{
    return Vector(_x, _y, _z) -= vector;
}

Vector& Vector::operator*=(double val)
{   
    _x *= val;
    _y *= val;
    _z *= val;  

    return *this;
}

double Vector::operator*(const Vector& vector) const
{   
    return this->DotProduct(vector);
}

Vector Vector::operator*(double val) const
{
    return Vector(_x, _y, _z) *= val;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& stream, const Vector& vector)
{
    return stream << "x: " << vector._x << ", y: " << vector._y << ", z: " << vector._z;
}
```

Comment: @0x499602D2 no it doesn't :)

Comment: I would suggest that you implement binary operators (+, -, *, etc.) as non-member functions.

Comment: I'd transfer it to CodeReview SE

Comment: 1.> See [GOTW4](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/) for improving your operator functions. 2.> It is a bad idea to reuse names from the `std` namespace. You should change `vector` to something else

Comment: Most of your stuff looks OK. [This post](http://herbsutter.com/2013/05/20/gotw-4-class-mechanics/) could be quite useful in improving it.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the quick response.  I did not know about CodeReview SE, I will check it out.  Thanks for the feedback, the articles helped out a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- I would avoid the leading underscores on your attribute names. These particular names are legal but many led by `_` are not.
- `Length` and `LengthSquared` should be `const`.
- The compiler generated copy constructor and destructor will do the right thing - no need to write them yourself and risk a copy-paste error.
- Consider making `DotProduct` and `CrossProduct` non-member, non-friend "algorithm" functions. Also consider this for the non-mutating operators (which can then be written in the canonical form `T operator+(T left, const T& right) { return left += right; }`
- Strongly consider not providing an `operator*` at all as it's not intuitive if it means scalar, dot, or cross product. Use named methods instead.

Comment: It's largely a matter of taste and application, but I'd suggest considering changing the internal representation from three disjoint `double` variables to an array of three doubles (e.g. `double components_ [3];`.) This gives a better guarantee on memory layout and additional benefits like the ability to implement an efficient (and pretty) `operator []` which is obviously useful in many contexts.

Comment: This is a big change, but I personally would have templated my implementation on the number of dimensions. Combined with `static_assert` (or `enable_if`) to exclude compilation of obviously incorrect cases (e.g. calling `GetZ()` on a two-component Vector) and defining some (free) functions only for the cases that make sense (e.g. cross product for 3D vector only,) this will give a more general, more useful and equally efficient implementation.